# Illustrator: Brush without gap

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

Can some one tell me how to use Brushes in Illustrator so that when I draw complete paths such as Rectangles and Circles the stroke doesn't taper off like it does here:
[image: Art brush with tapered end]

Comment: Use pattern brushes, not art brushes.

Answer (score 2):

Two main options; modify your brush or modify your path...

#### Change your brush...

This won't completely remove the gap but modifying your brush to not stretch the open ends will help a bit. From the brush options dialog set the scale options to "Stretch Between Guides" and drag the guides inside the problem areas.

The following example shows the same art brush applied before (top) and after (bottom) modifying the brush scaling options:

[image]

Another option is to modify the artwork itself. Drag the brush from the brushes panel to your document, chop off the ends so that you have clean straight edges, drag the artwork back to the brushes panel to create a new brush:

[image]

Or probably the easiest option...

#### Change your path...

Simply extend your path so the open ends overlap (I've separated the paths on the right just to show you how the path is constructed):

[image]